# Which statistical significance test to use for specific finance experiment?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, finance

I'm in the middle of my empirical analysis. My goal is to show the behaviour of the CDS-bond-basis of European banks after a rating downgrade occured. I have all my data gathered and cleaned.

My dependent variable is the change of the CDS-bond-basis. It is a numerical, continous variable. I have only one independent variable, namely the time interval after a downgrade. It is a categorical variable with four different groups: [-30,-1], [1,30], [31,60] and [61,90]. Whereas for example [-30,-1] stands for the time interval between 30 days before and 1 day before a downgrade.

In my whole dataset I have 546 downgrades, therefore n=546 for each interval.
Now I would like to state the mean of each group (interval) and whether it is statistically significant from 0.

I checked that my data is homoscedastic using Levene- as well as Fligner-Killeen test, both returned positive results. The data is more or less normally distributed when I had a look at the histogram and the QQ-plot, however the Shapiro-Wilk showed a non-normal distribution, however the small discrepancy seems no problem becuse of the large sample size. Therefore I can apply a parametric test.

My first idea was to use linear regression, however I'm not sure if this is possible given the nature of my two variables.

Could anyone give me some advice which statistical test to use in my research?

I would be extremely thankful for any kind of help.